# Pointer scopes in C

Tags: c, pointers, puts

In the following code, the explanation for the failure to print anything is that the pointer returned by get_message() is out of scope:

```
char *get_message() {
    char msg [] = "Aren’t pointers fun?";
    return msg ;
}

int main (void) {
    char *foo = get_message();
    puts(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

When run in gdb, it turns out that the data at the position of foo is the string "Aren't pointers fun?":

```
Old value = 0x0
New value = 0x7fffffffde60 "Aren’t pointers fun?"
```

(This seems consistent with answers which states that the data for a pointer which passes out of scope remains in memory), but the documentation for "puts" states first data is copied from the address given: presumably 0x7fffffffde60 in this case.

Therefore: why is nothing output?

**EDIT**: Thanks for your answers: 
I ran the original code to completion in gdb, the call to puts does indeed change the data at the address where foo was stored.

```
(gdb) p foo
$1 = 0x7fffffffde60 "Aren’t pointers fun?"
(gdb) n

11      return 0;
(gdb) p foo
$2 = 0x7fffffffde60 "`\336\377\377\377\177"
```

Interestingly, the code **did** print the message when I changed the code for change_msg() to:

```
char *get_message() {
        char *msg = "Aren’t pointers fun?";
    return msg ;
}
```

In this case, the data at foo (address 0x4005f4 - does the smaller size of the address mean anything?) remains the same throughout the code. It'd be cool to find out why this changes the behaviour

Comment: Why is nothing output?  You've invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: An array is **not** a pointer.

Comment: @Olaf: While this is true, I fail to see how it is relevant here.

Comment: @undur_gongor: OP returns a local array. If `msg` was a pointer, it would work.

Comment: @Olaf: OP returns a pointer. A pointer to a "local" array. But a pointer. You cannot return arrays.

Comment: @undur_gongor: Thank you for the information. I do not talk about the return type, but `msg`. Try `char *msg = "Hello"; return msg;`. According to the rest of his question, OP confuses pointer and array: "... that the data for a pointer which passes out of scope ..." Data of a pointer is the address it points to. Data for an array is the contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable msg is allocated on the stack of get_message()

```
char msg [] = "Aren’t pointers fun?";
```

Once get_message() returns, the stack for that method is torn down.  There is no guarantee at that point of what is in the memory that the pointer returned to `foo` now points to.

When puts() is called, the stack is likely modified, overwriting "Aren't pointer's fun."

Comment: gdb shows that the string is still there and pointed by foo. The problem is not there.

Comment: @Yves: At what point?  The call to puts likely modifies the stack.

Comment: Exactly. Upon return of get_message the message is still there.

Comment: Yes, and in `puts` that part of the stack gets overwritten.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Yes, but when puts() tries to *access* it, the call to puts() has already modified the stack.  The function call return address and possibly parameters (depending on the compiler) will be placed on the stack.

Comment: Your sentence " There is no guarantee at that point of what is in the memory that the pointer returned to foo now points to" isn't valid. gdb shows that the string is still there (and there's no reason it would be different).

Comment: I mentioned in my answer, the message would technically still be on the stack, but anything put on teh stack (beyond another function call) would overwrite it. It's really best not to tempt fate with that.

Comment: This discussion of "when is or isn't the string still present on the stack?" is interesting enough that I'll touch on it in a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that calling `puts` modifies the stack and overwrites the string.

Just returning from `get_message` leaves the string unchanged, but deallocated, i.e. its memory space is available for reuse.

Answer (score 1):

The real question here is not, "why doesn't it work?".  The question is, "Why does the string seem to exist even after the return from `get_message`, but then still not work?"

To clarify, let's look at the `main` function again, with two comments for reference:

```
int main (void) {
    char *foo = get_message();
    /* point A */
    puts(foo);
    /* point B */
    return 0;
}
```

I just compiled and ran this under gdb.  Indeed, at `point A`, when I printed out the value of the variable `foo` in gdb, gdb showed me that it pointed to the string `"Aren’t pointers fun?"`.  But then, `puts` failed to print that string.  And then, at `point B`, if I again printed out `foo` in gdb, it was no longer the string it had been.

The explanation, as several earlier commenters have explained, is that function `get_message` leaves the string on the stack, where it's not guaranteed to stay for long.  After `get_message` returns, and before anything else has been called, it's still there.  But when we call `puts`, and `puts` begins working, it's using that same portion of the stack for its own local storage, so sometime in there (and before `puts` manages to actually print the string), the string gets destroyed.

---

In response to the OP's follow-on question: When we had

```
char *get_message() {
    char msg [] = "Aren’t pointers fun?";
    return msg ;
}
```

the string lives in the array `msg` which is on the stack, and we return a pointer to that array, which doesn't work because the data in the array eventually disappears.  If we change it to

```
char * msg = "Aren’t pointers fun?";
```

(such a tiny-seeming change!), now the string is stored in the program's initialized data segment, and we return a pointer to *that*, and since it's in the program's initialized data segment, it sticks around essentially forever.  (And yes, the fact that `get_message` ends up returning a different-looking address is significant, although I wouldn't read too much into whether it's lower or higher.)

---

The bottom line is that arrays and pointers are different.  Hugely hugely different.  The line

```
char arr[] = "Hello, world!";
```

bears almost no relation to the very similar-looking line

```
char *ptr = "Hello, world!";
```

Now, they're the same in that you can do both

```
printf("%s\n", arr);
```

and

```
printf("%s\n", ptr);
```

But if you try to say

```
arr = "Goodbye";    /* WRONG */
```

you can't, because you can't assign to an array.  If you want a new string here, you have to use `strcpy`, and you have to make sure that the new string is the same length or shorter:

```
strcpy(arr, "Goodbye");
```

But if you try the `strcpy` thing with the pointer:

```
strcpy(ptr, "Goodbye");    /* WRONG */
```

now *that* doesn't work, because the string constant that `ptr` points is nonwritable.  In the pointer case, you can (and often must) use simple assignment:

```
ptr = "Goodbye";
```

and in this case there's no problem setting it to a longer string, too:

```
ptr = "Supercalafragalisticexpialadocious";
```

Those are the basic differences, but as this question points out, another big difference is that the array `arr` can't be usefully declared in and returned from a function (unless you make it `static`), while the pointer `ptr` can.

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of `msg` ends when returning from the function `get_message`. The returned pointer points to the object whose lifetime has ended.

Accessing it yields undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

In your case, the memory of the former `msg` seems to be overwritten with 0 already.

And this is not about "scope". You can fix your code by making `msg` `static`. This does not change the scope but its lifetime (a.k.a. storage duration).

Answer (score 0):

In your getMessage function, the memory used by your message is on the stack and not on the heap. Its still a pointer, just to a location on the stack. Once the function returns, the stack altered (to get the return ip etc) when means, although the message MIGHT still be in the same location in memory, there is absolutely no guarantee. If anything else puts something on to the stack (such as another function call) then most likely it will be overridden. Your message is gone.

The better approach would be to allocate the memory dynamically with malloc to make certain the string in on the heap (although this leads to the problem of who owns the pointer and is responsible for freeing it.)

If you must do something like this, I have seen it done using static:

```
static char * message = "I love static pointers";
```

Edit: despite mentioning that is MIGHT still be on the stack, NEVER EVER ASSUME it is. Most languages won't even allow this.

Comment: If you want to declare and return `char * message = "I love pointers"` you don't need the `static`.  What `static` is good for in this case is making the array return well-defined also: `static char message[] = "I love static arrays"`.